# How to update a lookup field using a web service

Tags: sharepoint-2010, caml

I have a Nintex workflow and I am using a "Call Web Service" action to add a new list item in another site. I want to update a lookup field in the destination list from a lookup field in the source list. This is my CAML query

```
<UpdateListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <listName>Kaizen Blast Objectives</listName>
            <updates>
              <Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" ViewName="">
                <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
                  <Field Name="ID">New</Field>
                  <Field Name="Title">{ItemProperty:Title}</Field>
                  <Field Name="Event_x0020_Driver">{ItemProperty:Event_x0020_Driver}</Field>
                  <Field Name="Problem_x0020_Statement">{ItemProperty:Problem_x0020_Statement}</Field>
                  <Field Name="Group1">{ItemProperty:Group}</Field>
                </Method>
              </Batch>
            </updates>
        </UpdateListItems>
```

"Group1" is a lookup field in the destination list and "Group" ({ItemProperty:Group}) is a lookup field in the source list.

A simple assignment like I have doesn't seem to work.

**EDIT**
The lookup field in the destination list is a site column.

Any ideas?

Comment: What was the final format of your statement: <Field Name="Group1">{ItemProperty:Group}</Field>, if you don't mind me asking?
I'm having a similar problem updating lookup fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. When updating a lookup field the format has to be id;#value. This is true even if the source and the destination fields are of the same data type.